# Display each item in loop

Tags: php, email

I have a form that post an array and I loop over the array which I want to display in an email.

```
$qty = $_POST['qty'];
foreach($qty as $value)
{
  $qtyOut = $value . "<br>";
}
```

I then want to get the `$qtyOut` of each one and display in my email.

my email looks like so.

```
$message = "An order was submitted from: " . $additionalEmail . "<br/><br/>"
. "Customer Name: " . $custName . "<br/>"
. "Email:" . $customerEmail . "<br/>"
. "Message: <br/>"
. "<pre>" .$custName . "<br> "
. "Qty: ". $qtyOut . "Desc: " . $desc . "Options :" . $options . "Price : " . $price . "</pre>"
. "Submitted at: ". $time;

$message = wordwrap($message, 70, "\r\n");
```

I would like to have the:

```
. "Qty: ". $qtyOut . "Desc: " . $desc . "Options :" . $options . "Price : " . $price .
```

Display as many times as there are order lines to fill the email.

Can somebody point me in the right direction please, as only the last line is displayed that was entered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are redefining your `$qtyOut` variable. 
Instead of

```
$qtyOut = $value . "<br>";
```

Use:

```
$qtyOut .= $value . "<br>";
```

Comment: It just displays `Array1 2` where 2 was the last item inputted so it has displayed Array1 first which should of been 1 and then 2 which was the 2nd item entered.

Comment: Please be more specific, your comment is quite confusing. And please share the `qty Array`, and also the final output

Comment: The qty array is just in a form input. it gets serialized using `jQuery` and each first element that is displayed has the word `Array` in front of the value being displayed. Which is strange.